# conda remove openssl breaks iPython, conda, and pip

Tags: python, openssl, pip, uninstallation, conda

While trying to resolve package dependency problems, I used conda to uninstall `openssl`, since this appeared to be one of the packages with unsatisfiable specifications. However, once I did this, conda, iPython and `pip` broke with the error message

```
ERROR:root:code for hash md5 was not found
```

I tried to re-install `openssl` with the homebrew package manager but `brew install openssl` notifies me that `openssl` has already been installed.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Comment: @jww: There are **a lot** of questions on SO about installing software.  For example, with numpy, searching "[numpy] install" brings up over 10% of the total, python "[python] install" is a higher percentage.  If it's a policy of SO to call these questions off topic, could you please provide a link that points this out.

Comment: `brew uninstall`/`brew install` or whatever the appropriate `brew` pair would be? Alternatively, have you tried installing from source?

Comment: @tom10: *"There are a lot of questions on SO about installing software"* - it sounds like they should be closed too (but I did not bother looking at them, so I could be wrong about some of them). Or, merge Stack Overflow and Super User so everything is on-topic.

Comment: @jww: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/88900/programming-environment-outside-scope-of-stackoverflow

Comment: @Tom - I'll retract the close vote if you can convince this this question is primarily related to programming. If its not, then I'll keep the close vote. I think its going to be a hard sell, though. How to install/delete packages, how to search in a text editor, etc are not primarily related to programming. As such, they should be taken to a more appropriate site. (Or, merge Stack Overflow and Super User so everything is on-topic).

Comment: Thanks @Tom, that was actually my own question posted on Super User, at your recommendation. I hadn't appreciated that SO was not appropriate for installation questions. My bad.

Comment: Since the question is about using conda, a python distribution that manages python packages, I would not vote to close as off-topic. If anything I would CV on "demonstrate minimal understanding." OP seems to be confusing openssl libs and python bindings..

Answer (score 1):

The latest version of openssl in conda (1.0.1k) should have this issue completely fixed.

Comment: just a question, doesn't conda check packages for broken dependencies upon removal of a package?

Comment: @marscher it does now. It didn't when this answer was written.

Answer (score 0):

`iPython` in the `conda` distribution is going to look for `openssl` in the `conda` environment only.  Therefore, installing `openssl` with homebrew shouldn't have any impact on this, and won't fix your `conda` environment.  To fix this, you need to get the `conda` version of `openssl` working.

Unfortunately, I suspect that `conda` is going to need its version of `openssl` to get anything and do any fixing (it's usually installed first thing, even with the `miniconda` distribution) so it seems that you're likely stuck.  Fortunately, it's easy to install `conda` so you could just start from scratch.

I'm a beginner with conda myself, and I am uncertain of all of the above, but it's my current understanding.

Comment: Thanks, tom10. I couldn't figure out how to fix the problem, so I just did a system restore from a mirror back up I'd made earlier that morning. Annoying, but I didn't lose much.